# Users can favorite their own questions?

Tags: support, bookmarks

Why can a user favorite their own question? This seems repetitive and generally useless for two reasons:

1. The user already gets notified of any question updates.
2. It makes it look as though other users like the question.

So, why does this feature even exist, and can we disable this action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "Favorite" feature is borderline useless; the only real function it serves is to allow you to build a list of questions you might wish to refer back to later.

Given there's no particular reason why you *wouldn't* want to occasionally refer back to your own posts... And plenty of reasons why you *might*... It makes little sense to disable this.

Note that favoriting a question is not always an indication that someone *likes* it. More than a few people have used this to remind themselves of questions that are troublesome and may need to be dealt with later.

Comment: I have noticed a trend of 1-rep users doing this... Maybe they think that this helps promote their post?

Comment: New users tend to like clicking things. A good way to teach them how to use the site is to put lots of things they can click in their way, and then explain what they just did after they've clicked. This guidance *has* to be automated though; we learned that lesson after the ill-fated "*kill a support person* button" incident.

Comment: *click*​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: '"kill a support person button" incident.' link or didn't happen.

Comment: I use this feature ***extensively***, typically to bookmark my most-often-needed posts to find them quickly among the hundreds of posts I have on *some* sites.